# Update statement returning 0 rows affected

Tags: sql

I am having issues with an update statement where I need to change the employeeid field from 4 to 6 for orders that have an order date of 7-19-1996

the statement i made is saying 0 rows affected when i know for a fact there are several rows that fit this description. Can someone steer me in the right direction as far as why am i getting this result and what I did wrong? Thanks
here is the statement I have so far

```
UPDATE [dbo].[LMOrders]
SET [EmployeeID] = 6
WHERE OrderDate= 7-19-1996
```

Comment: Need quotes around your date, and also needs to be in the correct format.

Comment: Did you run a SELECT first? Execute `SELECT EmployeeID, OrderDate FROM [dbo].[LMOrders] WHERE OrderDate = 7/19/1996` and see what results you get. If you don't get results with that SELECT, you won't get rows updated.

Comment: Is `OrderDate` datetime?

Comment: Provide date in proper format. If you say more details about you DB and table schema I can guide you.

Comment: To see/debug what will get updated, make an equivalent SELECT statement to your UPDATE statement.

Comment: @ken white when i run the select statement in the new query window it doesnt return anything but i know that these rows exist because when i do it this way i get to results

Comment: Have you tried in this format Where OrderDate = '1996-07-19' ? See answer below

Comment: @minimay: Clearly, your UPDATE was wrong, as the failure of the SELECT demonstrates (and as you've seen from the answer BrianAtkins gave you). Don't forget to come back and accept his answer when you can, so others know it has the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `OrderDate` is `DateTime` then you need to format your `WHERE` cause correctly: '2007-05-08 12:35:29.123' or if `Date` then '2007-05-08'

Here is a great resource, at the bottom of the doc shows the different formats
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: Thankyou ok i changed it now it works thanks this is the proper syntax                                                                                                                  UPDATE [dbo].[LMOrders]
            SET [EmployeeID] = 6
           WHERE  (OrderDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '1996-07-19 00:00:00', 102))

Comment: Great!  Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

The `OrderDate` here is wrong in any database. If I assume a `OrderDate` as a String, you can always do `WHERE OrderDate= '7/19/1996'`

If you need a conversion to date, since with [dbo]. I assume you're with mssql, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-CA/library/ms187928.aspx for conversion.

Comment: @ JFPicard  it seems people just do it as my whole topic is down voted as well